# Sort Asc and desc in the same column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a date column in a table, and I want to create a SELECT query that the **result order** of that query will be that all the dates that is bigger or equal to today's date will be first and the order should be ASC , and all the dates that is smaller than today's date will be second and the order will be DESC

The order should look like this:

notes:

1. In the following list the date format is YYYY-MM-DD
2. Today's date is 08 in Feb 2021
3. My date's data type is `date`

```
2021-02-08
2021-02-09
2021-05-18
2022-06-29<----This is the last bigger and equal then today
2021-02-07<----This is the first smaller then today
2021-02-06
2021-01-03
2020-12-06
2020-10-08
```

```
    ;with cte
    as
    (
    select 
        CustomrId
        ,CustomrName
        ,SubscriptionDate
        ,SubscriptionInDays
        ,datediff(day, dateadd(DAY, SubscriptionInDays, SubscriptionDate), CAST(GETDATE() AS Date )) as DaysToEnd
    from 
        TBL 
)
select 
    CustomrId
    ,CustomrName
    ,SubscriptionDate
    ,SubscriptionInDays
    ,-iif(DaysToEnd > 0, 0 ,DaysToEnd) as DaysToEnd
from 
    cte
order by 
        case 
            when DaysToEnd = 0 then 0
            when DaysToEnd > 0 then 1 
        end
        ,DaysToEnd



In this approach this is the result order I'm getting:
2021-02-08
2021-02-09
2021-05-18
2022-06-29<----This is the last bigger and equal then today
2020-10-08
2020-12-06
2021-01-03
2021-02-06
2021-02-07<----This is the first smaller then today
```

Comment: *"my date format is YYYY-MM-DD"* Date and time data types don't have a format, they are binary values. If your data *is* being stored in a "format", it is by defintion *not* a `date` and likely a `varchar` (a major design flaw). As for the question, what have you tried? This looks like you just want a few `CASE` expressions.

Comment: What I meant was that in the list I wrote in the post the dates are written in a YYYY-MM-DD format. (I will edit the post)

Comment: Thanks but you didn't include your attempt(s) when you did. Please do, and explain why they didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need conditional sorting:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN datecolumn >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
  ABS(DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()), datecolumn))
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0d03904fc93e1ed45ff6bba5b328464f).
Results:

| datecolumn |
| --- |
| 2021-02-08 |
| 2021-02-09 |
| 2021-05-18 |
| 2022-06-29 |
| 2021-02-07 |
| 2021-02-06 |
| 2021-01-03 |
| 2020-12-06 |
| 2020-10-08 |

Comment: Elegant solution! It can be obfuscated by forcing in [`Sign`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sign-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): `select TN.* from TableName as TN cross apply ( select DateDiff( day, Cast( GetDate() as Date ), DateColumn) as Delta ) as Diff( Delta ) order by -( Sign( Delta ) - 1 ) / 2,  Abs( Delta );`. The extra fiddling around `Sign` is to get the current date to drop into the correct half of the sort.